# what happens to rna length if we have a termination site in additional to the original one

Tags: molecular-biology, rna

if we have an RNA transcription and we add an additonal temination site in  the middle , will i have two RNA molecules or just a short one ?

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by termination signal you mean transcription termination signal (and not a stop codon), you would have one shorter RNA molecule. You can have two shorter RNA molecules if there is another transcription start site after the termination signal, but there is no reason to assume this will be the case.

In some cases the RNA polymerase will skip a base and frameshift while transcribing a new RNA strand. This is known as transcriptional slippage, and it is taken advantage of by some viruses in order to make their genomes more compact by having several different mRNAs overlap each other.

In this rare case, having a termination signal does not necessarily mean transcription will terminate, it might be able to skip through parts of the termination signal and continue to the next termination site.